# Cannot read preferredPresentationSize of NSItemProvider

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios-extensions

I have a share sheet extension through which my app can present itself as one of the options that shows up when user choses to share an image from camera roll.

I want to get the metadata about the image and its size without actually reading the whole data.  I see that `NSItemProvider` class has a property called `preferredPresentationSize`.  However, I am not able to read this property or the `sourceFrame` property (basically when I try to do a `X.preferredPresentationSize` in a `NSItemProvide` instance, Xcode complains that `preferredPresentationSize` is not a property in `NSItemProvider`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While `NSItemProvider` is on both iOS + OSX, `preferredPresentationSize` is a OSX SDK only property.